Chrome Extension & SingIn SignUp in an external website
We have:

A Chrome extension where we invite users to SignIn/SignUp once they click on a button from the extension and get redirected to the website of the extension.
A website that handles authentication from users clicking from the extension
A supabase setup.

Now once the user does the SignIn/SignUp, how do we make sure that the Chrome extension will get any sort of updates that the user is logged in so we update data and ui.
Thanks

one way to do this would be to add a content.js script that will listen for click events on the SignIn/Up button and then send a postMessage to the extension background.js to update the storage.
